# Need a span in ACF wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently working on a counter for my wordpress text fields (ACF plugin). The counter I made is in native JS (input + span to display the counter) works well on a classic html page. The problem is that in the ACF fields, there is no possibility to create "span". I looked to make my ACF fields myself in php but I can't find any solution...
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea I can come up with would be to pass whatever value to a Flexible Content field or Repeater field via the `update_row()` function. Here is the documentation for the function: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_row/